# how do I set a color to a spefic/certain buttons in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I have a ButtonManger.cs file which takes an array of buttons. I want to know how I can change all the buttons colors by the empty object(My ButtonManger Object). so basically once a button(that is in the array) is trigged/clicked it will tell the buttonmanger to change the color of the buttons(in array).

````
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ButtonManger : MonoBehaviour
{

   public Button[] button;

   public string selectedButton { get; private set; }

   private void Awake()
   {
       button = FindObjectsOfType<Button>();
       selectedButton = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;
   }
   public void OnClickedButton()
   {
     
           GetComponents<Button>().material.color = new Color(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.6f, 0.3f); 
//this is where I cant get it to work, getComponents<Button>().material doesnt work
 
   }
}```
````

Comment: Encapsulates a method to retrieve the corresponding button from the array. Assign the color to the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job for me:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeButtonColor : MonoBehaviour
{
    Button[] buttonsArray;

    void Awake()
    {
        buttonsArray = FindObjectsOfType<Button>();
    }

    public void ChangeButtonColors()
    {
        var newColor = Color.blue;

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            buttonsArray[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = newColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Change the color to your preferences on the first line of code under the ChangeButtonColor method.

Go to your buttons that and attach this method to whatever buttons you want.

[image]

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Vlad

Answer (score 0):

Material color can be set with:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html

Keep in mind that your material can have multiple colors based on the used shader. Default is _Color. I also recommend setting Color to public space so you can easily adjust it in the Inspector.

```
       public Color color_buttonpressed;
       public void OnClickedButton()
       {
               GetComponents<Button>().material.SetColor("_Color",color_buttonpressed);
       }
```